# Does the "table-making" tag serve a purpose?

Tags: discussion

The "table making" tag used [here](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5564/leg-basics-for-stools-chairs-table) has 14 uses and no tag wiki.  Would it be better to  apply the furniture tag and drop usage of table-making?  Or should we add a general tag regarding furniture assembly?

Answer (score 3):

I would lean toward adding the furniture tag and renaming table-making to table since a lot of the tags on this site could otherwise have the "-making" suffix.

I do think it would still be nice to be able to differentiate tables from chairs, beds, shelves, etc.

Comment: So you are advocating having tags for various categories of furniture such as "table", "chair" etc., and use the tag "furniture" for furniture-making?  We currently have a tag "furniture". If so we may want to distinguish between  them by editing the "Furniture" tag name to make it about the processes used eg. "furniture-making", "furniture-assembly", "furniture construction", or something similar. How many tags are too many?

Comment: It's easier to remove tags later if there are too many than it is to add them later if we want better differentiation between questions. There can be up to 5 tags on a question, and I would see the `furniture` tag as a more coarse category, similar to `power-tools`. I think the "-making" is somewhat implied unless the question is also tagged with `repair`. We do have different tags for various parts of the process, such as `design` and `finishing` so we could have a general tag for `assembly` as well, but "-construction" and "-making" don't seem to add much.

Comment: I like an "assembly" tag along with specific tags such as "table". I could help clean up the "table-making" tag if it is appropriate. Let me know.

Comment: A simple question.  How do you change the name of a tag.  I can edit the description but not the name.  Is this a moderator task?  The only option I could come up with is to make a new tag "table" and propose "table-making" as a synonym.